# How to Pass an array of objects that contains file from angular to .Net web api

Tags: .net, angular, file, webapi

Im using:  Angular 11,  .Net 6

I have an object that contains 2 properties. string and file

```
public class MyObj{
  public string strProp {get; set;}
  public IFormFile FormFile {get; set;}
}
```

In angular side im sending a list of MyObj objects:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('MyArr[0][strProp]', 'str0');
formData.append('MyArr[0][FormFile]', file0ToUpload, file0Name);
formData.append('MyArr[1][strProp]', 'str1');
formData.append('MyArr[1][FormFile]', file1ToUpload, file1Name);
_http.post<boolean>('https://...../MyMethod', formData)
```

In .Net web api controller im trying to get data from client:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("MyMethod")]
public Task<IActionResult> MyMethod([FromForm] List<MyObj> MyArr){
....
return Ok();
}
```

And I get a list with 2 items, the strProp contains data, But the FormFile is null

If I pass object and not array of objects it works fine, and FormFile  contains the file

How can I send an array of Objects that contains file from client to server?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative,

Instead of sending one array of objects, Im sending 2 arrays

first array contains the files

second array contains the other data + the file-name

on server side, I combine the files from first array to objects in second array using the file-name

So it looks like:

```
public class MyObj{
  public string strProp {get; set;}
  public string fileName{get; set;}
  public IFormFile FormFile {get; set;}
}
```

In angular side im sending a list of MyObj objects:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('MyArr[0][strProp]', 'str0');
formData.append('MyArr[0][fileName]', 'file0Name');
formData.append('MyArr[1][strProp]', 'str1');
formData.append('MyArr[1][fileName]', 'file1Name');
formData.append('files', file0ToUpload, 'file0Name');
formData.append('files', file1ToUpload, 'file1Name');
_http.post<boolean>('https://...../MyMethod', formData)
```

In .Net web api controller im get data from client, and combine the 2 arrays:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("MyMethod")]
public Task<IActionResult> MyMethod([FromForm] List<MyObj> MyArr, [FromForm] List<IFormFile> files){
  ....
  //merge 2 arrays using file-name that exists in 2 arrays 
  return Ok();
}
```